# C++ OpenGL: Calling gluPerspective throws an undefined reference error?

Tags: c++, opengl, perspective, freeglut, glu

I am using FreeGLUT to try and create my first cube in C++ with OpenGL.  I have an issue that whenever I call "gluPerspective", the compiler throws this error:

```
build/Debug/MinGW-Windows/main.o: In function `main':
C:\Users\User\Dropbox\NetBeans Workspace\Testing/main.cpp:47: undefined reference to `gluPerspective@32'
```

I have looked around to see if anyone has had this problem and found nothing.  So, I think I am being oblivious to something yet again.  Here is where I call the function:

```
......
glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
glLoadIdentity();

gluPerspective(45, 1.333, 1, 1000);
glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
glLoadIdentity();
......
```

I include freeGLUT and everything else works except that line.  I checked the documentation , and it seems as though I am using it correctly.  I am at a loss.

Comment: Before i answer the question you got: Why use the fixed function pipline? The FFP is deprecated.

Comment: I am just trying to get a basic working test down before jumping into shaders and whatnot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`gluPerspective` was removed from GLU (the OpenGL helper library) at version 3.1. Are you compiling against the correct library that still has it defined? If not then you will need to write your own version and pass the matrix direct to OpenGL.

OpenGL.org has [the gluPerspective code](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/GluPerspective_code) on it's website (presented here for completeness):

```
//matrix will receive the calculated perspective matrix.
//You would have to upload to your shader
// or use glLoadMatrixf if you aren't using shaders.
void glhPerspectivef2(float *matrix, float fovyInDegrees, float aspectRatio,
                      float znear, float zfar)
{
    float ymax, xmax;
    float temp, temp2, temp3, temp4;
    ymax = znear * tanf(fovyInDegrees * M_PI / 360.0);
    //ymin = -ymax;
    //xmin = -ymax * aspectRatio;
    xmax = ymax * aspectRatio;
    glhFrustumf2(matrix, -xmax, xmax, -ymax, ymax, znear, zfar);
}
void glhFrustumf2(float *matrix, float left, float right, float bottom, float top,
                  float znear, float zfar)
{
    float temp, temp2, temp3, temp4;
    temp = 2.0 * znear;
    temp2 = right - left;
    temp3 = top - bottom;
    temp4 = zfar - znear;
    matrix[0] = temp / temp2;
    matrix[1] = 0.0;
    matrix[2] = 0.0;
    matrix[3] = 0.0;
    matrix[4] = 0.0;
    matrix[5] = temp / temp3;
    matrix[6] = 0.0;
    matrix[7] = 0.0;
    matrix[8] = (right + left) / temp2;
    matrix[9] = (top + bottom) / temp3;
    matrix[10] = (-zfar - znear) / temp4;
    matrix[11] = -1.0;
    matrix[12] = 0.0;
    matrix[13] = 0.0;
    matrix[14] = (-temp * zfar) / temp4;
    matrix[15] = 0.0;
}
```

Comment: It might be the former.  The latter doesn't help at all.  But I am compiling with the latest version of FreeGLUT and OpenGL 3.3.0.  How do I get around this?

Comment: I guess I'll just search around.  Does OpenGL still have the matrix class or will I have to make my own?

Comment: @MrDoctorProfessorTyler - it still has the matrix class, and I've found the code.

Comment: Thanks! That is a really big help :D

Comment: gluPerspective **never** was part of OpenGL at all. It was part of GLU, a companion helper library, shipping with, but not being part of OpenGL-1.x

Comment: Still not correct. What happenes is that the GLU library never got updated ever since it came out. And now OpenGL outgrew it and it no longer fits.