# Pass matrix directly to OpenGL if glPerspective is undefined

Tags: c++, glut

When i try to call `gluPerspective` using g++ (MinGW) i get the error `undefined reference to` gluPerspective@32'`. I see that the function was removed in a previous version of GLU and found a workaround which should fix it https://stackoverflow.com/a/14793491/14709794

He wrote `to write your own version and pass the matrix direct to OpenGL` but how to do that? When i implement the 2 functions from the answer how do i call them instead of calling gluPerspective?

```
void reshape(int w,int h){

    glViewport(0, 0, w, h);
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();
    
    gluPerspective(60, 1, 2, 50);
    
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    
}
```

I tried

```
float *matrix;
glhPerspectivef2(matrix, 60, 1, 2, 50);
glPushMatrix();
```

As @rafix07 wrote i changed `float *matrix` to `float *matrix = new float[w * h]` and instead of `glPushMatrix(matrix)` i called `glLoadMatrixf(matrix)`.

```
float *matrix = new float[w * h];
glhPerspectivef2(matrix, 60, 1, 1, 500);
glLoadMatrixf(matrix);
```

Comment: Check `glLoadMatrix(f/d)`.

Comment: Can you tell me what you mean by f/d?

Comment: These functions are overloaded, one takes floats, the other doubles.

Comment: I tried right now with the same result.

Comment: Memory for your matrix must be allocated, for example `float *matrix = new float[16]` or just `float matrix[16]`.