# Undefined reference to gluPerspective() when building GLUT project with CMake?

Tags: c++, opengl, cmake, glut, glu

I am currently working on rendering 3D objects using the GLUT utilities in OpenGL. I am doing this on a Linux operating system, and are using CMake to compile the code. Every time I go to compile the code I get an 'undefined reference' error, but only for particular functions within the glad library.

My include directory in my `main.cpp` looks like;

```
#include <GL/glut.h>
```

And in my CMakeLists.txt file I have;

```
cmake_minimum-required(VERSION 3.17)

project(proj03)
add_executable({PROJECT_NAME} main.cpp glad.c)

find_package(OpenGL REQUIRED COMPONENTS OpenGL)
find_package(GLUT REQUIRED)

add_dependencies(${PROJECT_NAME} OpenGL::OpenGL GLUT::GLUT)

target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} OpenGL::OpenGL GLUT::GLUT)
```

Everything looks good at least for what I need, but when I run the make command within my build file in the bash terminal. I get the error;

```
[ 33%] Linking CXX executable proj03
/usr/bin/ld: CMakeFiles/proj03.dir/main.cpp.o: in function `reshape(int, int)':
main.cpp:(.text+0x790): undefined reference to `gluPerspective'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/proj03.dir/build.make:114: proj03] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:83: CMakeFiles/proj03.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [Makefile:91: all] Error 2
```

I've tried adding different libraries to see if the error would just go away that way, but it seems to only have this error for these particular functions within GLUT.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [C++ OpenGL: Calling gluPerspective throws an undefined reference error?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14793454/c-opengl-calling-gluperspective-throws-an-undefined-reference-error)

Answer (score 1):

[GLU](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenGL_Utility_Library) != [GLUT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenGL_Utility_Toolkit).

[FindOpenGL](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.17/module/FindOpenGL.html) defines several `IMPORTED` targets, including `OpenGL::GLU`.  Add that to `target_link_libraries()`:

```
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} OpenGL::OpenGL OpenGL:GLU GLUT::GLUT)
```

Though if you're using GLAD there's no reason to use the `OpenGL::OpenGL` target since GLAD handles linking against the system OpenGL shared library at run-time via `dlsym()` as well as providing all the OpenGL declarations itself.  You will however have to use `include_directories()` to point CMake at the GLAD `include` directory.  All together:

```
cmake_minimum-required(VERSION 3.17)

project(proj03)

find_package(OpenGL REQUIRED COMPONENTS GLU)
find_package(GLUT REQUIRED)

include_directories(SYSTEM "path/to/glad/include")

add_executable({PROJECT_NAME} main.cpp glad.c)
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} OpenGL::GLU GLUT::GLUT)
```